# Formatting an HTML Table

Tags: c#, html, css, formatting

I have a C# application that formats a list into a HTML table which is then sent as an e-mail through Outlook.

The issue I have is rather simple but I cannot resolve. I just want to change the font size of the whole table. No matter what I do the font size does not change. My code is below and I'm aware its not pretty!

```
string htmlHeader = "<table><font-size=3;><tr><th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Name</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th text-align:left>Ex Date</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Dividend Type</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Dividend Contribution</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Dividend Value</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Currency</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Country of Incorp</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";            
string msgBody = htmlHeader;

for (int i = 0; i < bbergList.Count; i++)
{
    string caText = "<tr><td>" + bbergList[i].Sedol + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].Name + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].dtEx.ToString("dd-MMM-yy") + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].DividendType + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].DividendValue.ToString("#,0.####") + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].DividendAmount.ToString("#,0.####") + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>"
                        + bbergList[i].DivCurrency + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>"
                        + bbergList[i].CountryInCorp + "</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}

StringBuilder sbFinish = new StringBuilder();
msgBody = sbFinish.Append(msgBody).Append("</font></table>").ToString();
```

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated. Use css to style fonts in your table.

Comment: how do I use css to style fonts in C#?

Comment: Globally in a "*.css" file, inline `<td style="font-size: 14px">`

Comment: See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) for some guidance in setting the styles.

Comment: You can't do a global CSS file for an email. But with the inline like you shown should work

Comment: You can use inline style css for Html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<table style="font-size:14px">
```

you can set the font size to whatever you want.

For a row:

```
<tr style="font-size:14px">
```

For a column:

```
<td style="font-size:14px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you tried to format your text with C#, but as you want to publish it as html code, I would suggest to use html tags to format:

You can find different examples for formatting text like subscript etc. here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

And if you want to change color, this example could help:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp

from obove site:

```
<font color="color_name|hex_number|rgb_number">
```

Use `<font color="red">This is some text!</font>` to get red colored font.

Best regards,

Marcus